# Pi Zero onboard time lapse camera read only file system?

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, camera, readwrite

I'm trying to build an onboard time lapse camera for my motorbike using a Pi Zero and a Pi camera powered by a USB port of my 5V 2.1A charger socket which has a on/off switch.
since I'd rather avoid another switch to power the Pi off before, can I use a read only file system for the sd and a usb stick to store the images?
this way I shouldn't damage the sd or the usb stick except in the rare case when I shut it down when is storing an image right?
but I could workaround this using a led that lights up for some second before the Pi takes an image.
or even better, can I achieve this by creating 2 partitions on the sd, a read only one for Raspbian and a read write one for image storing?

Answer (score 0):

You can have read-only root FS and you can also borrow a trick from various "boot CDs" or live images like [UnionFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS). Having separate storage partition should be easy and you can fsck it and even reformat if fsck fails.

Comment: so do you advice UnionFS with a read-only partition for the OS and a read-write partition for storing the images on the same sd? and powering it off suddenly in the worst case I'll get an image corrupted?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. You can afford to call `sync` after writing an image you definitely have one corrupt file at most. Otherwise only what is not yet `sync`-ed to the disk. You can run fsck at boot and even reformat the RW partition to make it "always work" if fsck fails... Logs, if needed, can be stored on the same or another RW partition.

Comment: could the SD be damaged? what about using a read-only SD for the OS and a USB stick or USB SD adapter for image storing? it would be safer?

Comment: Using USB stick is better and you may even get better IO speed. USB sticks (AFAIK) are also more durable, so it will last longer. This also will enable you to swap the sticks (but you have to handle it - discover the device, mount and/or format it...).

Comment: Ok I'll configure the SD as described here https://learn.adafruit.com/read-only-raspberry-pi/overview
so that I can switch between read-only and read-write using a jumper, any advice on USB stick file system?

Comment: Check https://askubuntu.com/questions/232208/what-kind-of-filesystem-do-you-recommend-for-usb-flash-drive - I would use ext4 - fast and very reliable, but I use Linux everywhere. UDF looks promising option. FAT is universally working, but it has way too many limitations (file size, permissions, timestamps are +-1 second). If you want to plug the USB stick anywhere and see photos - FAT...

Comment: So ext4 being a journaling fs should be incorruptible, except for hw damage which I hope to avoid, maybe I could add a LED which lights up when the camera is saving images so that I can prevent shutdowns when is on

Comment: The tricky part is that you should do [sync](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sync) after saving the image and before turning off the LED (because of the caching...) to be 100% sure it is saved.

Comment: anyway in the worst case I get a corruped file, not a damaged USB stick right?

Comment: yes, the USB stick/drive itself will not be damaged.

Comment: last, USB sticks are better than USB SD adapters for this purpose and why?

Comment: I have no reference for this, but I remember reading that MicroSD cards are not as durable as USB Sticks... less read-write cycles. I think it was in an article about Raspberry PI 3's new feature to boot from USB stick.

Comment: so SD cards have shorter life than USB sticks as general rule, not just in this case? the read-write cycles depend only on how much data is written, not on the number of Raspberry powers on/off right?